# Shortest Path Passing Through All Points When Start and End Points are Given

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, hamiltonian-path, dynamic-programming

Assume we have a set of points $\{A,B,C,\dots,Z\}$ in a plane.
What is the shortest path which includes all points once, starts at $A$ and ends in $Z$ and $A \ne Z$

I am trying to identify if this has the same complexity as the Traveling Salesman Problem.

---

Actually I have found that this is the "Messenger Problem" or "Wandering Salesman Problem" which is NP-Hard so it has the same complexity as the TSP.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Euclidean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they have the same complexity.  To reduce to TSP, introduce a dummy node that is adjacent only to $A$ and $Z$.

For a linear reduction in the other direction, you can solve any instance of TSP on $n$ nodes with $n-1$ calls to an oracle for your problem, as follows.  Fix any node $A$ and for each $j \not= A$, consider the edge $\{A,j\}$, with length $c_{A,j}$.  Solve your problem with $A$ and $j$ as the endpoints, yielding path length $p_j$.  An optimal solution to the TSP instance corresponds to $\arg\min\limits_{j\not= A} \{c_{A,j}+p_j\}$.

Comment: Thanks, but would not this point affect the whole solution?

Comment: There is a one-to-one correspondence between your $A$-$Z$ paths and tours that include the dummy node.  Furthermore, the lengths differ by a constant, namely the sum of the distances from $A$ to the dummy and from $Z$ to the dummy.  If you like, define these distances to be 0.

Comment: I would have thought that shows it does not have more complexity than TSP but not that it cannot have less

Comment: For a polynomial reduction in the other direction, consider all $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of nodes to be endpoints of the path.

Comment: @Henry, even better is a linear reduction.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: @RobPratt I would say the last statement of answer is not obvious and need a proof.

Comment: @Gevorg, this is essentially Bellman’s equation.  Each optimal TSP tour uses some edge (in fact, two) incident to node $A$. Once the edge is fixed, the remaining path must be an optimal solution to the OP’s problem (by optimality of the tour).